# How to delete desired duplicate entry using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to get rid of duplicates from my table. I got the duplicates like this:-

```
SELECT col1
FROM table_01
GROUP BY col1
HAVING ( COUNT(col1) > 1)
```

table_01 has another column 'col2' **which is nvarchar** that contains date and time. This col2 has **NULLs as well**. Now how can keep the latest entry (by date) and delete other duplicates. I have no clue? Pl. help.

Comment: Highlighted that the alleged "date" column is actually nvarchar. Strongly recommend that you reconsider using a datetime column for col2. Why would you want to store date/time information as a string? You lose a lot of capability by doing this and also open yourself into allowing all kinds of junk data, invalid dates, etc.

Comment: I agree with you. But thats how the existing system is working. Changing it to datetime is out of my scope.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col1, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
      PARTITION BY col1 
      ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, COALESCE(col2, '19000101')) DESC
    )
  FROM table_01
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: Col2 column is nvarchar and it contains date.

Comment: Why is Col2 not a datetime column? Need more information if you want to correctly determine "last" - what is the format of the data in this column? Can you please show some sample data?

Comment: Aaron: Col2 has NULL entries as well. That means out of duplicates, one entry is null (for few records only). I prefer to keep that record where it is not null.

Comment: Can't add logic for that *new* requirement until you *show* what a *valid* value looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of a correlated subquery. You said the two records have a different value for another column which contains dates and you want to delete the older record?

```
DELETE FROM tablea
WHERE tablea.dateentered < (SELECT MAX(i.dateentered)
                            FROM tablea i
                            WHERE tablea.id = i.id)
```